# Where can I find a good VCS written in PHP?

Tags: php, version-control

I have a web server which can run PHP and Ruby.

I would like to know if there is a PHP program which can do version control of my code similar to SVN?
I know there are already open source project hosting sites which provide this service already but I would like it to be installed on my own host.
I don't have the access to this server to install additional packages either

Comment: I edited your question to make it more clear. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am in the same boat with shared web hosting through GoDaddy. It seems the best two options are still ASVCS and EasyPHPVCS. If you've found anything better, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/asvcs/ - Haven't tried this. But this sounds like what you are after.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of any version-control system written in PHP. But even if there were one, I'd stay away from it. Version control isn't one of the things a scripting language is best used for.

Edit: I suggest installing Subversion on your local machine and develop all the code there, that way the SVN on your local computer can be used for version-control.

Edit 2: If you are collaborating with others and want them to have access to your repositry, I suggest getting subversion hosting somewhere for your project. There are some free hosts out there that support it, just google it and you should find some results.

Comment: The only actions I can use is use FTP interpret PHP so how do I use another VCS that it isn't written in PHP?

Comment: And how do I do when I am not on my computer, sorry, but I need a server open 24h/24h  that's the interest. But thankx even.

Comment: version control is only used when you make any changes to your code, no? So I don't understand what the server being online 24/7 has to do with it? What will you use the version control for?

Comment: "Version control isn't one of the things a scripting language is best used for." I think Matt Mackall, the developer of Mercurial, would like a word with you out back.

Comment: @NathanAdams Python and PHP are completely different beasts..python is run as its own process, PHP is usually a module to apache, there's no possibility of multithreading in PHP, etc.

Comment: "pthreads is an Object Orientated API that allows user-land multi-threading in PHP." http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php .

Comment: @NathanAdams It is also a pain in the ass to set up, unlike Python which comes with it out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

For the same reasons - want to store the data on my own web site, which only supports PHP - I've created [phpEasyVCS](http://phpeasyvcs.sourceforge.net). It offers a web interface and WebDAV access.

Answer (score 1):

For what I know WEBSVN is just a way to view your SVN repository

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Why on earth would you care about the language of a tool that you use? That's like complaining that the builder of your house used a wooden ladder instead of a metal one.

Use [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) or Git or anything you want, they'll all work fine.

Comment: But I can't installed package or compile on the server do you understand?

Comment: Yeah, if you have shared hosting, you probably can't get anything running, other than a PHP App.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an online service such as [http://unfuddle.com/](http://unfuddle.com) or http://cvsdude.com/
They have free basic plans and even their paid plans are cheap enough to make it worth it.

Comment: I have said in my post 'I know there are already open source project hosting which provide this service already but I want it installed on my own host.' then I think I will uses WebSVN.

Answer (score 0):

If you need VCS somewhere that is not your computer and the production site is not under your control either, I would agree with nandos that you should use online service.

Then in order to put changes in production you could make PHP script on production site that accesses the online service and downloads the newest version via HTTP (http should be generally available with CVS, and SVN uses it natively) rather than using specific VCS protocols.

You will have limited options, but that's not what generally is expected to be controlled from production anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think nobody has really answered to my question.
I said that I don't want any hosting facilities like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_free_software_hosting_facilities.
So I think I will use http://websvn.tigris.org/
Thanks.

Guillaume

Comment: So what you really wanted was a web based svn repository browser?

Comment: Yes but WebSVN requires SVN, so it doesn't fix my problem. I think there is no issues to my question

Answer (score 0):

Why must the VCS be written in PHP? You could use SVN as the VCS and serve the files using apache. I can't think of a single benefit of wrestling with yet another version control system. What you could do is get a virtual machine appliance for source code control and issue management like [vmTrac](http://www.garghouti.co.uk/vmTrac/) and either run it directly or pick it apart and figure out how it was put together

Comment: But I can't install SVN or CVS because it is a shared hosting

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for reference, since you have FTP access, you could use [Bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/) over FTP, and use something like [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) as a webviewer. Using FTP would be slower than installing the Bazaar smart server on the server (FTP is known as a "dumb" transport), but it would meet all your requirements.

Hope that helps someone

-Scott